# duplicate a column of a csv by deleting a character

Tags: powershell

I have a problem to solve in PowerShell.
I have a csv with two columns (column1 and column2) and I want to create a third column (column3) with the same information as the first column by eliminating the "dot"

```
column1  column2  column3  
1.         AA        1
2.         BB        2
3.         CC        3
4.         DD        4
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `Import-Csv` cmdlet to import the data from the original file, then use `Select-Object` with a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-7.2) to create a new property corresponding to a new column, then finally export to disk again with `Export-Csv`:

```
Import-Csv path\to\input.csv |Select-Object column1,column2,@{Name='column3';Expression={$_.column1 -replace '\.$'}} |Export-Csv path\to\output.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

The expression `$_.column1 -replace '\.$'` will take the value of the `column1` property on each row, and replace a literal dot `` occurring at the very end of the string with nothing (thus removing it if present, otherwise not doing anything).